# How to create a audit mapplet in Informatica?

Tags: informatica

I want to create an audit, which can be re-used across multiple mappings to capture `Source` record count and target record count in  when source database is oracle and target database is sql server

We are using it from source to staging mappings

Comment: Regardless of where your source and target are you can get this info from the repository metadata tables e.g. rep_sess_log and rep_sess_tbl_log ... see here for more https://network.informatica.com/thread/26104

Answer (score 0):

It's all there, in Metadata tables. There's no need to add anything that will make your loads longer and more complex.

You can review [this Framework](http://powercenternotes.blogspot.com/2014/01/an-etl-framework-for-operational.html) for some ideas.